# save result of ndarray to image

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing

I have an image I take a snippet of, I am trying to save the snippet to a file.

1. get image using getPixels
2. snip section of ndarray (my goal is the top left corner)
3. save the ndarray a new image

My code:

```
var getPixels = require("get-pixels");
var fs = require("fs");
var savePixels = require("save-pixels");

let img='path_to_img_file'
getPixels(img, "image/jpeg", function (err, pixels) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Bad image", err);
    return;
  }

  pixels = pixels.hi(50, 50, 50); //subset
  savePixels(pixels, "png").pipe((p) =>
    fs.createWriteStream(p, "shot.png")
  );
```

My error:

`Unhandled error. ('No data provided')`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var getPixels = require("get-pixels");
var fs = require("fs");
var savePixels = require("save-pixels");


let img='./output.png'

getPixels(img, "image/png", function (err, pixels) {
     if (err) {
        console.log("Bad image", err);
        return;
    }
    // Save to output2.png
    savePixels(pixels, "png").pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./output2.png"));
});
```

I think your issue was that you did

```
.pipe((p) =>
```

and the usual syntax, to the best of my knowledge, is

```
readableStream.pipe(writeableStream)
```

rather than

```
function.pipe((readableStream) => writeableStream.pipe(readableStream));
```

Comment: I believe you are missing the line: `pixels = pixels.hi(50, 50, 50);` in your example. That is the line that is causing all my issues (when I do the subset)

Comment: That line was causing issues, but I could remove it and not worry about it. The code I included worked perfectly on my end; let me know if it has issues on yours.